# Facebook login error in android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Edited

I tried to add Facebook credentials to log my android application. i added fb login button to project.so it take my username correctly. but when other user login it did not take the new user name.

I used [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) to developed my application.

i want to use FB credentials as my application login details.

This is code i used

```
@Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //authButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
        @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                   // welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");

                    welcome.setText(user.getName() + ","
                            + user.getUsername() + ","
                            + user.getId() + "," + user.getLink()
                            + "," + user.getFirstName()+ user.asMap().get("email"));

                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }

        });
      }

      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: are You getting any error.....

Comment: search not work ne. @NagarjunaReddy

Comment: explain your problem with little bit clearly..